# How many watts of electricity can the human body withstand without being killed?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, power, biology

I'm talking about DC and/or AC. I've read about people surviving extremely high voltage shock (300kV) but that could be explained by extremely high resistance in the circuit that resulted insufficient current to cause death.

Comment: Another important figure is energy itself $E=t V^2/R$, where $t$ is the time duration. I seem to remember reading somewhere that 2 Joule is already dangerous. Of course if those 2 Joule are dissipated in two days I don't expect anything too bad to happen.

Comment: It depends on where the current flows.  Through the heart or brain – big problem.  Hand to elbow – painful but probably not deadly.

Comment: The answer will depend on what part of the body is exposed to the electrical power.

Answer (score 1):

The main driver for the effect of electricity on the human body is current, not Voltage or Power (Watts).

The interaction is complicated, so you can't easily apply a single number to "safe" or "deadly". Effects are can be neurological, chemical and thermal. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_injury